# How to set page orientation for Word document?

Tags: java, apache-poi, landscape-portrait, orientation-changes, xwpf

I use [Apache POI XWPF](https://poi.apache.org/document/) to create and handle `MS Word` documents. But I didn't  find in the documentation how to change the page orientation.

Apparently this way should make it:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

CTDocument1 document = doc.getDocument();
CTBody body = document.getBody();

if (!body.isSetSectPr()) {
     body.addNewSectPr();
}
CTSectPr section = body.getSectPr();

if(!section.isSetPgSz()) {
    section.addNewPgSz();
}
CTPageSz pageSize = section.getPgSz();

pageSize.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

But this method doesn't work properly. I can set the page orientation to landscape, and when I read the page orientation in the code, I get landscape. All right. But if I open the saved document I've portrait format. This setting doesn't work in fact. What could be the problem?

As a workaround, I'm forced to start work with a blank document created manually in landscape or portrait format. But I want to create documents programmatically from scratch in needed orientation.

For instance [POI HSSF and XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet) have functionality to toggle between landscape and portrait mode. It's [setLandscape()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PrintSetup.html#setLandscape(boolean)) method of `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PrintSetup` interface.

But what about `XWPF` or `HWPF`?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI FAQ on what to do when a CTsomething class isn't in the poi-ooxml-schemas jar](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your remark. But this does not resolve my issue. I added right versions of all the necessary jars. And I don't get any exceptions, everything compiles and runs. But the subject is still actual. **How to change orientation of document correctly?** The above code does not work properly. 
I've set the page orientation to landscape in the above manner, but I continue to see portrait format when I open the document.

Comment: If you set a document to Landscape in word, save as .docx, then unzip the resulting file (.docx is a zip of xml files), where does the orientation actually get set?

Comment: That is Apache POI cannot solve this problem?

Comment: It probably can do, but it'll need a little bit of work, as apparently no-one so far has needed this feature enough to submit a patch...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were very much on the right path.  Setting the orientation to landscape describes the general orientation of the paper, but will still need the *size* of the paper.  Your CTPageSz object doesn't have that yet.

This means in addition to your setOrient call, you'll need to both setW and setH.  These calls take BigIntegers that are representative of 1/20 Point.  For a landscaped LETTER type paper therefore, you'll just:

```
pageSize.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(15840));
pageSize.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(12240));
```

For Word to recognize it as Landscaped, the width must be greater than the height.  You still want to keep the setOrient call as well if you want it to behave properly when going to print.

Here's some common paper sizes in points from https://www.gnu.org/software/gv/manual/html_node/Paper-Keywords-and-paper-size-in-points.html  you should take these and multiply them by twenty to use in the above method calls

```
Letter       612x792
LetterSmall  612x792
Tabloid      792x1224
Ledger       1224x792
Legal        612x1008
Statement    396x612
Executive    540x720
A0           2384x3371
A1           1685x2384
A2           1190x1684
A3           842x1190
A4           595x842
A4Small      595x842
A5           420x595
B4           729x1032
B5           516x729
Folio        612x936
Quarto       610x780
10x14        720x1008
```

Comment: In landscape mode not able set header, any solution? @Zach

Answer (score 2):

Answer is right.

I just had to add extra dependencies to be able to access CTPageSz class.

```
// SBT config
"org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "4.1.0",     // Base library
"org.apache.poi" % "ooxml-schemas" % "1.4",   // required to access CTPageSz
```