# Apache POI docx - how to set page size?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

Does anybody know how to change page size (from letter to A4) for `XWPFDocument` (docx)?

I cannot find any PrintSetup like it is done in XSSFDocument (xlsx).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm stuck at this as well. Surprisingly, this is the only question I came across and it was asked just a week ago!

Comment: @Swapnil  I have no solution yet :-) I left this for the moment, but I'll have to back to the problem. Please help if you find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find similar question like your's here ..You'll find a sample code plus the required page sizes

[How to set page orientation for Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188953/how-to-set-page-orientation-for-word-document)

I hope this could help!