# JODConverter Page Orientation

Tags: java, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I'm using JODConverter to convert my office files into PDF, using this simple code:

```
officeDocumentConverter.convert(origin, destination, destinationFormat);
```

But the problem is that OpenOffice (or JODConverter, I don`t know) isn't respecting the page orientation of my documents. Every document stays in a portrait format. Even if the document pages are in landscape format.

Is there any option to turn on that kind of detection or respect my page orientations?

Comment: Since JODConverter is simply using Open Office to convert your files, what happens if you use Open Office to do it manually?  Doing it by hand will give you a valuable diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - in JODConverter you can't do it, because it is properties of input document, not output.

About this -

> Even if the document pages are in landscape format.

My JOD version is 2.2.1 and I can reproduce this problem for Word document and can't for Excel. You can try to change Word input document orientation - [How to set page orientation for Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188953/how-to-set-page-orientation-for-word-document#24500643) programatically